# capturing the time that the issue spent in each department

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a custom list that used to manage the issues and complaints of customers and there is a column called "Dept." to show where the complaint is right now. Once the issue is closed, I want to know how many days have been taken by each department to complete the issue. Any one can help please?

Answer (score 0):

High level, I think your best best is to write the updates that occur on each list item in your issue list to another list or perhaps a database where you can then analyze the length of time between department transitions for each issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you define “*close*”, but you can build a flow to trigger on item modification and update the days between the last modification day and `Created` to a custom column.

The process of the flow would be as following:

*When an item is created or modified* > *Condition*: `Closed` is equal to `Yes` > If yes: *Update item*.

And `Duration` =

```
div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'])),864000000000)
```

[image]